# Slicing Python lists vs Slicing R vectors

Tags: python, r

In `R` I can do this

```
> a = (10:19)
> a
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
> b = c(4,7)
> b
[1] 4 7
>
> a[b]
[1] 13 16
>
> a[-b]
[1] 10 11 12 14 15 17 18 19
```

I suppose there is an equally elegant way of doing this to Python (2.7) lists, but haven't found yet.  I'm particularly interested in the `a[-b]` bit. Any thoughts?

[edit]
  a is [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19], b is [4,7] (indices into a)

Comment: I'd tell you if I knew what `a` and `b` looked like, and what `c()` meant.

Comment: @2rs2ts: edited to show you what `a` and `b`are; `c()` is for concatenation. in python, `a = range(10,20)` and `b=[4,7]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using list comprehensions

```
[n for n, i in enumerate(a) if i not in b]
```

Or using numpy:

```
x = np.arange(10, 20)
y = [2, 7]

x[y]
```

Comment: +1 good answer and actually the only one that will really work

Comment: @Justin correct me if I'm wrong, but the problem with the numpy solution is that we cannot do `x[-y]`, or can we?

Comment: You're correct.  I coulda sworn there was a [tag:pandas] version of this... and you can always do the list comprehension on a numpy array (of values or indicies).

Comment: The conclusion that I draw from this is that, despite being more elegant and intuitive than `R`, Python lost on this one.

Comment: if by lost you mean took more characters then yes... from a developer standpoint something like `a[-b]` is very confusing in python since python allows negative indexing (r may also I dont know)

Comment: @JasonBeasley what I find really confusing is that one can do `a[2:4]`, but cannot do something like `a[1,3]` nor `a[[1,3]]`. But that's me coming from `R`.

Comment: You most certainly can do `a[1,3]` and `a[[1,3]]`... they just may not mean what you think they do (fwiw, you can't do that in R either! your first example would give you the first row and third column, second example (replacing with `c(1,3)`) would give you the first and third columns (much like a numpy array would...)

Comment: @Justin `>>> a = range(10,19)` `>>> a[1,3]` gives `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    a[1,3]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`

Comment: Yes, to have multi-dimension arrays you need to use `numpy.array`.  I'd suggest spending some time getting familiar with the basics of `numpy` and particularly `pandas`.  you'll find a lot of R-isms there.

Comment: @Justin--there's nothing multi-dimensional on what I was trying to achieve. I just wanted to slice a python list so that I could get two arbitrary elements, without having to rely on a sequence like 2:10 or 2:11:3. More, I wanted to slice a list based on another list. As you showed, can do this is python without having to load numpy. All I'm saying is that, to my eyes, this operation is less elegant than its `R` counterpart. (btw, I tried to edit the answer and reverse the `n,i` to `i,n` but I guess I haven't got enough rep for that.)

Answer (score 2):

```
 a=numpy.array(range(10,20))
 b = [4,7]
 print a[b]
 print a[~numpy.in1d(a,a[b])]
```

not quite as elegent but meh  ... it also wont work if there are duplicate elements in the list ... since its looking at the values in the negation step rather than the indices

Answer (score 0):

You probably want numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(range(10,19))
b = [3,6]
a[b]
=> array([13, 16])
a[[_ for _ in range(len(a)) if _ not in b]]
=> array([10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 17, 18])
```